# Como verificar se String esta contida em uma posição de um array?

Tags: javascript

Preciso verificar se em uma String, contém alguma palavra que esta no array.

Por exemplo:

```
var array = ['faço?', '**fazer**' ]
var str = 'como eu posso **fazer** isso?'
```

Teria alguma forma mais eficaz e com melhor desempenho de fazer essa verificação, ou só usando laços para verificar as posições do vetor, e comparando com a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para uma verificação simples podes fazer assim:

```
var existem = ['faço?', 'fazer' ].filter(function(palavra{
    return str.indexOf(palavra) != -1;
});
```

E se a array `existem` tiver `length > 0` é porque existem palavras da array na string e estarão dentro dessa array. Este método é simples e dá positivo no caso da frase que indicaste mas também no caso de:

> "Vou des**fazer** a mala agora."

mas neste caso talvez seja um falso positivo... para corrigir isso podes fazer assim:

```
var filtros = ['faço?', 'fazer'];

function palavras(str, arr) {
    var existem = arr.filter(function(palavra) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\\s' + palavra + '[\\s,\\.\\?\\!]');
        return str.match(regex);
    });
    return existem;
}

var testeA = palavras('como eu posso fazer isso?', filtros);
var testeB = palavras('Vou desfazer a mala agora.', filtros);

console.log(testeA.length > 0, JSON.stringify(testeA)); // dá: true "["fazer"]"
console.log(testeB.length > 0, JSON.stringify(testeB)); // dá: false "[]"
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjnsoxgm/

Se quiseres somente `true` ou `false` e não precisas de saber que palavras podem verificar positivo então, [como o @BrunoBR sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128000/como-verificar-se-string-esta-contida-em-uma-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-array/128014#comment266942_128014) podes usar o [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) assim:

```
function palavras(str, arr) {
    return arr.some(function(palavra) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\\s' + palavra + '[\\s,\\.\\?\\!]');
        return str.match(regex);
    });
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjnsoxgm/1/

O `.some()` tem a grande vantagem de parar de procurar assim que o primeiro positivo fôr encontrado, poupando o processador.